# Rearranging binary digits

Tags: python, binary

Say I have a dictionary from [0,1...n] to [0,1...n]. I now want to convert between n+1-bit numbers by moving around the binary digits according to this dictionary. If n = sum(c_i*2^i), then f(n,dic) = sum(c_i*2^dic[i]), for whatever values c_i.

As some examples, lets say my dictionary is {0:1,1:2,2:0}, then 5, (101), would become 3, (011). Given a dictionary {0:3,1:2,2:0,3:4,4:1}, then 21, (10101), would become 11, (01011).

I'm trying to do this in python in a way which is relatively fast. I'm going to apply this transformation on all n+1-bit numbers, so right now I make an array to whose indices are keys for n+1-bit numbers, but it's quite slow.

```
def bit(dic):
    out = []
    for i in range(2**(len(dic)):
        appending = 0
        for k in range(len(dic)):
            if not i%2**k == i%2**k+1:
                appending += 2**dic[k]
        out.append(appending)
    return out
```

As a further question, in the case where multiple keys can correspond to the same value, n, according to dic, I want to return 2^(sum c_keys) if all(sum c_keys < 2) else -1, which seems rather annoying to check, is there a clever solution to this?

Comment: Are you concerned that the array generation is slow?  Or that using the array to transform a value is slow?

Comment: array generation, once it is made, transforming is just need to look up indices, which is certainly fast enough